# Send GET information with javascript

Tags: javascript, iridium

Hi i am trying to send GET information to a PHP site through JavaScript in an iRidium Mobile environment (**not** a web browser). 
I can't use JQuery due to the limitation of my development environment.

this is what I have so far:

```
function AjaxRequest(url,method){
  var req = createXMLHTTPObject();
  req.onreadystatechange= function(){
        if(req.readyState != 4) return;
        if(req.status != 200) return;
        alert(req.responseText);
  }
  req.open(method,url,true);
  req.send(null);
}
```

I get the error:

> Script exception: ReferenceError: createXMLHTTPObject

I am probably missing some library, but I don't know where to find it or an alternative.

Comment: I think you are looking for `var req = new window.xmlHttpRequest ? xmlHttpRequest() : ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")`... Ajax tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: Just my curiosity : What makes you preventing from using jQuery ?

Comment: Better to go with Jquery $.post or $.get.

Comment: Iam using iRidium Mobile its a development environment that is extremely handy with communicating with domotica and it supports Javascript but it doesn't have all the abilities like a webbrowser has. iRidium Mobile isn't very old so it has limitations, they are still improving but it still in the starting phase

Comment: @ErwinMaas Thanks for your reply , it makes me to search about `iRidium Mobile`

Comment: @Red this is their website http://www.iridiummobile.net/

Answer (score 0):

One possible method to access content data in Iridium Mobile is by using its own driver and configuring IP, port, protocol, etc. After that you can receive data directly inside Javascript app.

Check more details in:
http://dev.iridiummobile.net/AV_%26_Custom_Systems/en#AV_Custom_Systems_(Client)